# Performance reduce in Android release mode

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, mobile, pdf.js

I develop an mobile application with Ionic and i use PDF.js to show all PDF files for my users. It's completely work without problem BUT i don't now why, in release mode (after sign and build my adb files and deploy to Google play console), my PDF is so slow to render. I don't have the problem in IOS...

All PDF is scan of letters so they are all compose of images.

I try "crunchPngs false" in my build.gradle because i think the optimisation image is the problem but not...

I remark when i disable the worker, my loader is goes to the end of the load but is so slow...
I have no idea what i do now... Do you have an idea ?

Regards.